# max() arg is an empty sequence when solving Best Time To Buy and Sell Stock

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on a Leetcode problem called ["Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock"](https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock/).

> You are given an array `prices` where `prices[i]` is the price of a given stock on the `i`th day.
>
> You want to maximize your profit by choosing a single day to buy one stock and choosing a different day in the future to sell that stock.
>
> Return the maximum profit you can achieve from this transaction. If you cannot achieve any profit, return `0`.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> `1 <= prices.length <= 10**5`
>
> `0 <= prices[i] <= 10**4`

This is my solution:

```
class Solution:
    def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
        res = []
        for i in range(len(prices)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(prices)):
                res.append(prices[j] - prices[i])
        if max(res) <= 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return max(res)
```

I tested all cases on my IDE (VS Code) and it all passes. But, I got the error shown below when I submitted it on LeetCode. What's wrong with my code?

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
    if max(res) <= 0:
```

Comment: Leetcode will tell you the input that it failed on. In this case, it would tell you that `prices` only had one element in it.

Answer (score 1):

LeetCode tells you that the constraint on prices is:

```
1 <= prices.length <= 10**5
```

If `prices.length == 1`, then the inner part of your `for` loop will never fire, causing `res` to be an empty list.

One fix is to add an `if` guard at the top of your function, since you can't sell the stock on a different day if there's only one day to buy or sell:

```py
def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
    if len(prices) == 1:
         return 0
```

---

However, the runtime is quadratic in the length of the `prices` list, and with up to `10**5` days to consider, your approach will time out, even after adding the `if` guard.

Here is a linear time approach: essentially, for each day, you want to compute the cheapest stock price seen before that day and the most expensive stock price seen after that day. This allows you to only consider buy-sell possibilities that are feasible (i.e. they meet the constraint that you must buy a stock before you sell it.) The following code will pass LeetCode's test cases.

```py
import math
class Solution:
    def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
        min_prices = [0] * len(prices)
        max_prices = [0] * len(prices)
        
        min_price = math.inf
        max_price = 0
        for i in range(len(prices)):
            min_price = min(min_price, prices[i])
            min_prices[i] = min_price
            
        for i in range(len(prices) - 1, -1, -1):
            max_price = max(max_price, prices[i])
            max_prices[i] = max_price
        
        result = 0
        for minimum, maximum in zip(min_prices, max_prices):
            result = max(maximum - minimum, result)
        return result
```

Comment: Just for fun, you actually don't need all that extra memory. https://gist.github.com/sharth/272a6a3f9b994c3e34716e59bdb69ed1

Comment: Funnily enough, LeetCode says that my solution uses less memory than 98.9% of all Python submissions.

Comment: Weird, but true. The one I'm suggesting claims to use more memory than yours.

Comment: Not sure what's going on, though I will note that I have had issues with those statistics in the past (e.g. very large percentile jumps when repeatedly submitting the same code).